# How to limit HTTPS to one TCP connection?

Tags: http, tcp

I'm using uIP along with mbed TLS to run a simple web server on a microcontroller, and host an HTTPS page.

The problem is: my chip only has enough RAM to handle one TLS connection at a time, but Firefox (and Chrome) tries to open multiple connections at once to load the images on the page.  If I tell uIP to abort or close additional connections, Firefox assumes an error and gives up loading the rest of the page.

I can tell uIP to limit the total connections to 1, and in that case it just drops new SYN packets if there is already a connection.  This actually works, as Firefox will wait and try again until the page is fully loaded.  I can't use this a solution however, since I do need to allow more than 1 TCP connection total in order to handle other types of connections (I can serve a regular HTTP web page at the same time, for example).  If I could tell uIP to limit connections on a specific port to 1 at a time, that may solve the problem, but I don't think uIP has that capability.  I also don't see a way to force uIP to drop certain packets.

I've looked all over the web, but I can't find any information on running a web server using just one TCP connection at a time.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Marlon

Comment: What happens if you use two different ports and don't *accept* any SSL connections if you have one currently?

Comment: What happens if more than one person connects? Is this supposed to only be used by one person?

Comment: @Oasiscircle Part of the system spec is that it is limited to one person at a time when using the TLS web page.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I believe the way to not accept connections with uIP is to tell it to abort the connection, but this sends a RST packet back to the browser and causes it to stop loading the element.  I can also temporarily tell it to stop listening to the port, but that also causes it to send a RST when a new connection is attempted.

Comment: Don't tell it not to accept the connection, just don't accept the connection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Do you mean at the TCP level?  I agree with you I think, but the only options I can think of are to either ignore the SYN or send a RST.

Comment: No, I mean in the application. Instead of calling `accept` to accept the connection, don't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the replies.  I think I see what you're getting at (this is an embedded system running FreeRTOS so there is no accept function) but what I ended up doing was leaving the TCP connection open and just doing nothing on it.  Then once the previous TCP/TLS connection is finished, I handle the newly opened one.  Firefox and Chrome both seem happy to wait in this fashion.

So the problem is solved.  Although I can't mark your comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ignore the SSL connection until you are ready to process it. Browsers should tolerate this.